# android: sensor data (ACCELEROMETER+MAGNETOMETER) TO image plane offset

Tags: android, camera, offset, sensors

Here we go:
An android APP, I have extracted data from sensors(ACCELEROMETER & MAGNETROMETER) in my Desire HD, at the same time, I turn on the camera. what i am trying to do is to estimate the offset between two frames captured by the cam.

i have read a lot of QUESTIONS about this problem here, like gyro+acc+mag+kalman filter...Now with the data i extract from sensors (6DOF,3 for ACC, and 3 for MAG), I can get the RotationMatrix after calling the Android API. Then i have the rotation angle from world coordinate to camera coordinate.Also I can get the intrinsic parameters of camera through calibration, such as focal length, distortion coefficients...

So my question is : is it a right way to calculate the offset between two frames using the sensor data i got before, combining the angle and intrinsic parameters of camera?

any one has tried this out before?

REF: [Tsai Camera Calibration](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/DIAS1/)

Comment: By offset do you mean movement through space during the interval between when two frames were captured? Sounds like you know how to calculate change in directional orientation already. Kindly summarize what your study of answers produced and where you are stumped.